# Postion().top is not consistant due angular DOM still loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

Position top is not consistant every time ,
If user scrolls down when dom is still loading position will be different.

```
 angular.module('users').directive('appplyProperty', ['$window', '$timeout',
        function ($window, $timeout) {
            var $win = angular.element($window);
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                  var = offsetTop = element.offset().top;

                 $win.on('scroll', function (e) {
                    var checkTheTop = $window.scrollY - offsetTop;
                      if (checkTheTop > 0) {
                         // apply css property top = checkTheTop ;
                        } else {
                        //do something
                 }
                });
             });
          }
}]);
```

How to make sure position is calculated only after DOM is loaded or condition that now nothing is happening in the dom calculate position ?

Comment: try encapsulating your code in a $timeout - [link](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering/)

Comment: tried didnt work, I am not trying to check an element. I am trying to look for whole page to be loaded for some reason it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Use `ready` method to ensure that your angular DOM is ready.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $win.on('scroll', function (e) {
        var checkTheTop = $window.scrollY - offsetTop;
        if (checkTheTop > 0) {
            // apply css property top = checkTheTop ;
        } else {
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```